# KDE app theming using sudo in Unity

Tags: themes, kde, sudo, gtk

When I run Kontact as another user using `gksudo`, `gksu`, or `kdesudo`, the theming is all messed up:

[image: Kontact screenshot]

When I run Thunderbird as another user, it works fine! I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 using the Unity interface.

**How can I fix the theming of KDE apps when run as a different user?**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the 'Rodent' theme in gtk.
Apparently qt apps under *any different user* can not automatically pick up the desktop theme.

Run:

```
xhost +
gksudo -u youruser qtconfig
xhost -
```

from the command line. If it is not installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig`. Then set *GUI Style* to *Gtk+* at the first, *appearance* tab. Save and exit. Subsequent *'sudoed'* qt applications will pick up the running GTK theme.

However this might affect the looks of these apps when run under KDE. Perhaps file a bug report with the qt makers.

**EDIT:**
Effective today, 2013-02-27, there is a `qt-chooser`-package in updates which might help these issues.

Comment: I'm not trying to run this as root, just as another regular user. When logged into that user, KDE apps look fine, it's just when I try to run them as that user but logged in as my regular user that they look bad.

Comment: I tried running `qtconfig` and got this error: `qtconfig: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qtconfig': No such file or directory`. I think it is because I have the Ubuntu Touch SDK installed. When I tried to install `qtconfig-qt4`, `apt-get` says there is no such package.

Comment: Also, I justed tried running a KDE app using as root and it didn't pick up the theme either.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect this. Also fixed typo in package name.

Comment: I still can't get `qtconfig` to run and I get same error message as before. Also, I don't see any package similar to the new one you named.